# How to make my images look transparrent in my pdf document

Tags: floats, transparency

I'm trying to make my images look transparent in my output pdf using latex (MikTex 2.9).
and removing the bottom line.
Here is my tex code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=0.53in,right=0.83in,top=0.3in,bottom=1.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{100pt} 
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2.00cm,height=2.10cm]{17-001}}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=6.00cm,height=1.30cm]{17-000}\linebreak\linebreak
   \small{Pattern Recognition Letters 28 (2007) 1548–1555}}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=3.10cm,height=2.10cm]{17-002}\linebreak
\scriptsize{\href{http://www.elsevier.com/locate/patrec}{www.elsevier.com/locate/patrec}}}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards
[image: left image]
[image: center image]
[image: right image]
[image: Desired pdf output]

Comment: That's strange. Which viewer are you using? And what is the format of those images?

Comment: I extracted the images from a pdf file, which i'm trying to reproduce with latex, the format is "png". i will upload the images now.

Answer (score 1):

I extracted the images again from the pdf file using an online website and selected the "jpg" format instead of "png" format. I can see now that the background of the jpg's ones is white not like png ones which is black.Now i'm outputing my pdf using latex without any issues.
Best regards.